# Ubuntu 18.04 install rtl8821ce 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, kernel

My kernel version is: Linux Speedsters 5.4.0-86-generic #97~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Sep 18 03:11:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
And my problem is that I can not find the wifi adaptor after `rosdep update`. I have followed the instructions online. And their solutions are all stuck at the same place. While I did `sudo ./dkms-install.sh` or `make`, errors occurred. Like:

```
Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.4.0-86-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.5.2_34066.20200325 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.4.0-86-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325/build/make.log for more information.
```

And:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=5.4.0-86-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8821ce: v5.5.2_34066.20200325 not found
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and things like that. They didn't work.

Comment: There are many newer kernels then 5.4 you may be better off with say the 5.11